# Carousel with focusable items

Tags: scrolling, cards, carousel, input-focus

I have a carousel with partial display of the items on the far left/right. Every item has a button to open additional information under the carousel (the item then becomes "active" with some visual effect to make it stand out).

What is the best strategy for interacting with partially visible items?
I can think of a few solutions:

- Allow interaction and leave the carousel as is (seems weird to me)
- Allow interaction but scroll the item into full view
- No interaction (also weird if the item is almost fully visible)
- Modify the carousel to use some horizontal growing/shrinking of the items so that they are either visible or hidden, eliminating the issue

Comment: Any mockup to share?

Comment: It's only on pen/paper right now...

Answer (score 1):

A mix of first and second options could be working, you can allow interaction with partially visible items, but when users click on an item, the carousel smoothly scrolls it into full view to ensure clarity and avoid accidental clicks.

Alternatively, if your carousel can show tooltips or previews of additional information on partially visible items, users can get a glimpse of what they'll see when interacting with the item without requiring a full interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your input and ideas!
Had some discussions at work and we agreed to go for the last option to simplify things. A possible downside is with the variable item width, not sure if that will always look great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, this is a 4 columns carousel where you could see 3 items on to screen and 4th item is hidden little on to the right.

Allow user to click next button provided on the carousel, if not, add a next/prev button to access all the tiles of carousel.

Click next button the 4th tile will visible in full view and now click on it to check related information.

This same example can also work if you have are showcasing one item at a time on carousel. Simply next button push the next item on to screen, make it visible and you can click to check its information/details.

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Srija Nair